# Notational suggestion for Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app

I am using the iOS app for Stack Exchange and it's great; I have Math and Physics Stack Exchange and it is quite tiresome to render my own works and writings, especially for math.

Why doesn't Stack Exchange upgrade its keyboard to letters, symbols, and numbers? The symbols, for example, are the \sin button, the \cos button, the integral button, and so on.
This would make it very easy (since instead of writing codes by a single tap of a key, walla! a symbol pops up!) for the users, plus it would make it easier for the editors as well.

So why not make some?

Comment: Are you asking for a "\sin" button?

Comment: _Why doesn't Stack Exchange upgrade its keyboard_... Stack Exchange doesn't have its own keyboard for Android or iOS.

Comment: Using the iOS default keyboard is significantly easier than creating a custom keyboard from scratch or trying to find a premade one that has the features you want, looks good, and actually functions reliably.

Comment: @Catija are you saying its easier to use the iOS keyboard for the users or the creators or designers of the app?

Comment: @Socre everything about my comment relates to the **creation** of the keyboard.

Comment: @Catija I did not say change it all, just simply add new buttons which correspond to mathematical symbols for math site and other helpful symbols for other sites. There are many repetitive functions and symbols used and it wouldn't hurt adding them to the keyboards. Other symbols not used repetitively can be left and used as they always have been used.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not edit the built-in iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Per the previous comments, we use iOS's build-in keyboard for text input and swapping out a LaTeX keyboard would be a real hassle *for us*, so I don't plan to implement one.

That said, on iOS8 the app does support custom keyboard extensions and a quick Google search revealed [an app called MathKey](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mathkey-math-latex-keyboard/id932863429?mt=8) which appears to cover your exact use case.